# Bacula Device "FileStorage" requested by DIR could not be opened or does not exist

Tags: 14.04, backup, remote-access

i am trying to setup bacula to remotely backup my machine.

My Configuration looks like this:

```
Job {
  Name = "LocalBackup"
  JobDefs = "DefaultJob"
}

Job {
  Name = "RemoteBackup"
  JobDefs = "DefaultJob"
  Client = ClientMachine-fd
  Pool = RemoteFile
}

Job {
  Name = "RestoreRemote"
  Type = Restore
  Client=ClientMachine-fd
  FileSet="Full Set"
  Storage = File     
  Pool = Default
  Messages = Standard
  Where = /bacula/restore
}
```

And my client config looks like this:

```
Client {
  Name = ClientMachine-fd
  Address = ClientMachine.DomainName.com
  FDPort = 9102 
  Catalog = MyCatalog
  Password = "u2LK-yBrQzfiEsc6NWftHEhymmdPWsklN"          # password for Remote FileDaemon
  File Retention = 30 days            # 30 days
  Job Retention = 6 months            # six months
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired Jobs/Files
}
```

When i run this configuration and first find the status of my client i get the following message:

```
ClientMachine-fd Version: 5.2.6 (21 February 2012)  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu ubuntu 14.04
Daemon started 01-Oct-15 13:14. Jobs: run=0 running=0.
 Heap: heap=270,336 smbytes=15,823 max_bytes=15,970 bufs=48 max_bufs=49
 Sizeof: boffset_t=8 size_t=8 debug=0 trace=0 
Running Jobs:
Director connected at: 01-Oct-15 13:53
No Jobs running.
====

Terminated Jobs:
====
*
```

Now i wish to run my job i get the following message:

```
    01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-dir JobId 4: Start Backup JobId 4, Job=RemoteBackup.2015-10-01_11.54.23_05
01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-sd JobId 4: Error: dev.c:120 Unable to stat device /nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir: ERR=No such file or directory
01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-sd JobId 4: Warning: 
     Device "FileStorage" requested by DIR could not be opened or does not exist.
01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-sd JobId 4: Error: dev.c:120 Unable to stat device /nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir: ERR=No such file or directory
01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-sd JobId 4: Warning: 
     Device "FileStorage" requested by DIR could not be opened or does not exist.
01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-sd JobId 4: Error: dev.c:120 Unable to stat device /nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir: ERR=No such file or directory
01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-sd JobId 4: Warning: 
     Device "FileStorage" requested by DIR could not be opened or does not exist.
01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-sd JobId 4: Fatal error: Device reservation failed for JobId=4: Jmsg Job=RemoteBackup.2015-10-01_11.54.23_05 type=5 level=1443700465 BackupServer-sd JobId 4: Warning: 
     Device "FileStorage" requested by DIR could not be opened or does not exist.

01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-dir JobId 4: Fatal error: 
     Storage daemon didn't accept Device "FileStorage" because:
     3924 Device "FileStorage" not in SD Device resources.
01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-dir JobId 4: Error: Bacula BackupServer-dir 5.2.6 (21Feb12):
  Build OS:               i686-pc-linux-gnu ubuntu 14.10
  JobId:                  4
  Job:                    RemoteBackup.2015-10-01_11.54.23_05
  Backup Level:           Full (upgraded from Incremental)
  Client:                 "ClientMachine-fd" 5.2.6 (21Feb12) x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,ubuntu,14.04
  FileSet:                "Full Set" 2015-10-01 11:39:29
  Pool:                   "RemoteFile" (From Job resource)
  Catalog:                "MyCatalog" (From Client resource)
  Storage:                "File" (From Job resource)
  Scheduled time:         01-Oct-2015 11:54:21
  Start time:             01-Oct-2015 11:54:25
  End time:               01-Oct-2015 11:54:25
  Elapsed time:           0 secs
  Priority:               10
  FD Files Written:       0
  SD Files Written:       0
  FD Bytes Written:       0 (0 B)
  SD Bytes Written:       0 (0 B)
  Rate:                   0.0 KB/s
  Software Compression:   None
  VSS:                    no
  Encryption:             no
  Accurate:               no
  Volume name(s):         
  Volume Session Id:      2
  Volume Session Time:    1443699984
  Last Volume Bytes:      0 (0 B)
  Non-fatal FD errors:    1
  SD Errors:              0
  FD termination status:  
  SD termination status:  
  Termination:            *** Backup Error ***
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: That password is fake I assume? ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind THat password is superFAKE :D

Comment: Good ;) and if the 2 errors I posted about are not enough to get you going you probably need to add `bacula-dir.conf` and `bacula-sd.conf` to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding:

> 3924 Device "FileStorage" not in SD Device resources.

- The `Media Type` should be the same in both `bacula.sd.conf` and `bacula-dir.conf`.

> 01-Oct 11:54 BackupServer-sd JobId 4: Error: dev.c:120 Unable to stat device /nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir: ERR=No such file or directory

- You probably forgot to change the `Archive Device` since `/nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir` is the default it ships with.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer is the changes i need to make in the backupserver or the client?

Comment: Both need to have the same sort of info (so they match eachother) The 1st complains about "FileStorage" not in "sd" so I would edit it into that one for starters. The 2nd one is also complaining about "sd" but should be easier: I  believe you have the actual phrase "/nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir" in one of the config files. So "grep" for it ;)

Comment: @Rizwind on my client i have only installed bacula-client and i dont see that config anywhere ?

Comment: i made it to backup :D however im not quite sure what it took a backup off?  Do you have time to continue this in chat perhaps? :)

Comment: sorry no and I only dabbled with this a long time ago (we opted to create our own rsync in the end ;) )

Comment: it worked out? :)

Comment: @Razwind yeah i made it work perfectly :D

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the file storage device is not properly configured. Some years ago I did a lot with bacula, but now I don´t remember. But you need to check the config files for the bacula director daemon and the media deamon (bacula-dir.conf, bacula-sd.conf) and edit the Job properties for the "DefaultJob" in order to get a usable configuration.

```
JobDefs = "DefaultJob"
```

indicates that bacula tries to backup to a standard file storage device, which is properly not existing. Also this:

```
Storage daemon didn't accept Device "FileStorage" because:
3924 Device "FileStorage" not in SD Device resources.
```

Check the config of the storage daemon, you will be able to fix it then. Anyway, the defaults are rather obscure and only usable as example, so you need to scratch your head more and read the docs!